# How can I save and work with a JSON file in memory?

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm working on a Flask application with a POST route that will receive and process JSON files. These files cannot be saved to disk and must be saved to memory.

I can successfully pass a file to the route using the following code:

```
files = {'file': open('example.json', 'r')}
r = requests.post(URL, files=files)
```

The file is successfully received using the following code:

```
@app.route("/import", methods=["POST"])
def import_file():
    file = request.files['file'].read()
```

The file will be processed using a library (that I'm restricted from modifying) that will need to read/modify the file using the following code:

```
with open(file, 'r+', encoding='utf8') as f:
    # Do something
```

I've tried using StringIO and BytesIO but receive an "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object" error when trying to open using the code above. Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

Comment: `open(file, ...` expects a path, not another file. _Ideally_, the answer is "design a better API that accepts arbitrary file-like objects"

Comment: Right.  If you can't change the library that does an `open`, then you have no choice.  The file must go to disk.

Comment: Well, no _non-awful_ choice. If we count horrible things like monkeypatching as choices...

Comment: Could you use a RamDisk?

Comment: @GriffsAccount, ...do note that there do exist filesystem paths that live in memory -- `/dev/shm` etc; if your service is deployed with systemd it's easy to set up more (and if it's modern enough to use systemd, all of `/run` is likely to be memory-backed too, and it's a quick toggle to tell systemd to create a `/run/YourService` directory that your service can write to -- there are also security options to make that filesystem be in a process-local namespace so the rest of your operating system can't see it unless someone with root _really_ knows what they're doing).

Comment: I agree with @CharlesDuffy, perhaps monkeypatching `open()` is the easiest thing to do...

Comment: (...so perhaps it's worth reviewing whatever led to "cannot be saved to disk" as one of your requirements; once "saved to disk" is locked down enough to not touch an actual drive controller and to only be defeated by someone who _also_ has enough permissions to just steal the same secrets directly out of your Python process's memory, what's the point of saying "can't be saved to disk"?)

Comment: (the other thing about using a runtime directory managed by systemd is that it's automatically cleaned up when your Python process exits or restarts, just like other memory allocated by that process is, so there aren't any concerns about temporary files being left behind and creating a headache for your ops team).

Comment: For additional context, the application will be containerized and deployed in a Kubernetes namespace. I suppose I *can* write to disk, or could utilize emptyDir, which I believe would be comparable to /dev/shm. But I haven't used either before. Does that open you up to any other suggestions?